# Что не так с HTML'ем?)

Tags: html, html5

Недавно начал изучать `HTML`, уверен, что вопрос легкий для опытных программистов, однако я таковым не являюсь. Почему после того, как мы написали закрывающий тэг `</html>` , то после него еще можно писать код, который тоже будет выполняться? Я читал, что в `HTML5` этот тэг можно опустить, однако, я же, по сути, четко пишу, что на этом код закончился, почему же код, написанный после этого тэга, продолжает работать? И почему можно написать какое-то предложение вообще без тэгов и, опять же, после закрывающего тэга, и оно выведется на экран? Объясните, пожалуйста) Или это у меня какая-то ошибка и такого не может быть? Пользуюсь Sublime Text 3. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Это наследие прошлого. HTML очень толерантен к ошибкам. Так же в стандарте написано про неявное добавление тегов. Например, обратите внимание, что открывающий тег html тоже необязателен

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо)

Comment: Посмотри в самом браузере, действительно ли тег остался снаружи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все нормально. Просто написание тегов в теге html — это не жесткое правило, и если написать тег после `</html>`, ошибки не будет. Просто это стало хорошим тоном, и все разработчики пишут так. Насчет написания текста, так это просто html воспринимает как `<div>текст</div>`, и ничего такого в этом нет.

Comment: понял, спасибо)